# I get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" when i use remote container on VScode

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

Laravel project works fine using php artisan serve and xampp but i get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" when i use remote container on VScode.

docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laragigs
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=11111
```

I used this to install the project.

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis&devcontainer" | bash
```

I was hoping to send it to a colleague and be able to open it on another pc without a problem using the remote container on vscode. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you're using docker, the DB_HOST is most likely not 127.0.0.1. `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, I think the DB_HOST is 'mysql': `DB_HOST=mysql`, since your docker service name is mysql

Comment: thank you, DB_HOST was mysql and i was able to open it thru vscode remote container by  typing docker-compose up --build, which created a dockerfile. But when i sent it to a colleague, it didnt work on their pc.